# Can Audio Recorder record in stereo?

Tags: audio-recording

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 and audio-recorder - 0.9.1~precise. I am just wondering if it is possible to record a stereo file with this particular version? There doesn’t seem to be any documentation on this. All I could find was [an Ubuntu forums thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2237639) where someone said they would fix it in a later version, but it seems ambiguous in its response as to whether the app actually allows this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The post in that thread links to the [specific revision](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~osmoma/audio-recorder/trunk/revision/354) where it was fixed on 2014-08-05. The latest version is [1.5-4](https://launchpad.net/audio-recorder/trunk/version1.5-4) which was released 2014-10-10 to be available for 14.10 (as the author said it would be), so it includes that fix.

You can try installing the new version [from the PPA](https://launchpad.net/~osmoma/+archive/ubuntu/audio-recorder/+packages) but it may depend on newer software than you have with Precise.

You could also try compiling your version from source after making the fix yourself

Comment: You can try downloading 1.5-7 [from the PPA](https://launchpad.net/~osmoma/+archive/ubuntu/audio-recorder/+packages), but it may depend on stuff newer than Precise. Or you can try compiling yourself.

Comment: I dont think 1.5-7 os for Precise. Im going to edit the question to reflect the issue more specifcly